# Why getSymbols from quantmod keeps fail to connect in R?

Tags: r, yahoo-finance, quantmod

I am using getSymbols from quantmod package in R quite a long now but the last several days when i try to download some data i get the same error:

```
 library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("TSLA", from = "2011-01-01", to = "2022-01-31",auto.assign = TRUE)
Warning: TSLA download failed; trying again.
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "TSLA", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “TSLA”.
TSLA download failed after two attempts. Error message:
Failed to connect to query2.finance.yahoo.com port 443: Timed out
> getSymbols("TSLA", from = "2021-01-01", to = "2022-01-31",auto.assign = TRUE)
Warning: TSLA download failed; trying again.
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "TSLA", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “TSLA”.
TSLA download failed after two attempts. Error message:
Failed to connect to query1.finance.yahoo.com port 443: Timed out
```

Why is that happening ? I am not under firewall protection or proxy limitation.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, your first attempt worked.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I tried again but it keeps failing

Comment: update the package to the latest version 0.4.20.

Comment: @phiver what is the R command for that ?

Comment: @phiver via `sessionInfo()` i run the 0.4.20 version

Comment: 0.4.20 is the correct version. I don't have any issues using quantmod. Try again and make sure you are able to download data from yahoo, i.e. no firewall issues.

Comment: To get the package's version run `packageVersion("quantmod")`. Have you checked your internet connection?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes i have checked my internet connection is ok.The command reports me:  `packageVersion("quantmod")
[1] ‘0.4.20’`

Comment: @RuiBarradas i am writing you from the 3rd computer that i have tested the command and still not runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to fix `quantmod`, theres also `tidyquant`

```
library(tidyquant)

tq_get("TSLA", 
       from = "2011-01-01", 
       to = "2022-01-31")

# A tibble: 2,788 x 8
   symbol date        open  high   low close  volume
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 TSLA   2011-01-03  5.37  5.4   5.18  5.32  6.42e6
 2 TSLA   2011-01-04  5.33  5.39  5.20  5.33  5.94e6
 3 TSLA   2011-01-05  5.30  5.38  5.24  5.37  7.23e6
 4 TSLA   2011-01-06  5.37  5.6   5.36  5.58  1.03e7
 5 TSLA   2011-01-07  5.6   5.72  5.58  5.65  1.12e7
 6 TSLA   2011-01-10  5.63  5.74  5.61  5.69  6.71e6
 7 TSLA   2011-01-11  5.72  5.74  5.38  5.39  8.55e6
 8 TSLA   2011-01-12  5.40  5.48  5.30  5.39  4.82e6
 9 TSLA   2011-01-13  5.39  5.39  5.23  5.24  3.62e6
10 TSLA   2011-01-14  5.23  5.32  5.12  5.15  5.96e6
# ... with 2,778 more rows, and 1 more variable:
#   adjusted <dbl>
```

Comment: R reports me the following : `Warning message:
x = 'TSLA', get = 'stock.prices': Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "TSLA", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, : Unable to import “TSLA”.
TSLA download failed after two attempts. Error message:
Failed to connect to query1.finance.yahoo.com port 443: Timed out`

Comment: tidyquant is a wrapper around quantmod, so it won't work if quantmod isn't working.